# Is AJAX a separate language from Javascript, or is it a JavaScript framework?

Tags: javascript, ajax, frameworks

Basically, is AJAX similar to JavaScript in syntax and semantics?

Comment: The first sentence of the Wikipedia article could have told you that. Virtual -1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) isn't a language.  It's a methodology, using JavaScript and XML (and I guess JSON fits in there as well), for a web client to asynchronously communicate with a server resource without requiring user-enacted browser events (such as page navigation).

Comment: thats what I meant, is it a separate language, or its a strategy(like DOM) and languages like Javascript can implement the strategy.  thanks.

Comment: DOM isn't a strategy, it is an API.

Comment: CORRECTION, there IS a DOM api for javacript, but DOM alone is a strategy specified by w3c

Answer (score 2):

AJAX stands for Asynchronus Javascript and XML: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Ajax is a javascript methodology to get data from a server in real time. It's syntax (particularly when used in things like jQuery) is just javascript... Today you can simply use one function to make an ajax call (using jQuery):

```
$.ajax({ url: "test.html",  success: function(){/*do stuff here*/}});
```

**Old school** ajax (as mentioned below, late 90's early 00's) looks more like this: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Globals?! Is this 1997? Oh, W3Schools, it **is** 1997.

Comment: ahaha, thats why i said **old school** ajax :P i still remember using that for the first time in high school early 00's :S

Answer (score 1):

Actually, "AJAX" is short for `Asynchronous JavaScript and XML`. It is merely an asynchronous method of downloading data using Javascript.

Comment: thats what I meant, is it a separate language, or its a strategy(like DOM) and languages like Javascript can implement the strategy. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. It refers to the task of making (using JavaScript) an HTTP request (and handling the response to it) without the user leaving the current page (e.g. by following a link or submitting a form).

There are several ways to do this (XMLHttpRequest, generating `<script>` elements, using a hidden iframe, etc) and many libraries (YUI, Mootools, Prototype, jQuery, Glow, etc) that implement helper methods to make it easier.

So it isn't a language, an API, a library or a framework. It is just a thing that can be done (in various different ways).

(It has also been used as a term to replace "DHTML", but its usage for such as since been replaced by "HTML 5" — marketeers need a new buzzword to describe "Doing any kind of fancy stuff on the web" every few years)